# Surprising result with "fontenc" when \detokenize is applied to `-`

Tags: detokenize

Whether `\detokenize` is applied to `-` or `--` under the `fontenc` package `T1` fonts the results are the same.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lcl}
Command    & applied to        & result                    \\\hline
Verb       & two minus signs   & \verb=--=                 \\
Detokenize & two minus signs   & \ttfamily\detokenize{--}  \\
Detokenize & one minus sing    & \ttfamily\detokenize{-}   \\
Detokenize & three minus signs & \ttfamily\detokenize{---} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It's as if `\detokenize` is allowing some kind of expansion occur before applying its magic to its argument.  But I thought that's exactly what it's not supposed to do.

Could someone explain what's happening here?  And, why the difference with `\verb`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With both xelatex and lualatex I get the same result with or without `\detokenize` which is as expected as `-` has catcode 12 by default, so `\detokenize` just returns the same tokens as its argument in this case. Ligatures are not done via catcode tricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lcl}
Command    & applied to        & result                    \\\hline
Verb       & two minus signs   & \verb=--=                 \\
Detokenize & two minus signs   & \ttfamily\detokenize{--}  \\
Detokenize & one minus sing    & \ttfamily\detokenize{-}   \\
Detokenize & three minus signs & \ttfamily\detokenize{---} \\
\end{tabular}


\begin{tabular}{lcl}
Command    & applied to        & result                    \\\hline
Verb       & two minus signs   & \verb=--=                 \\
Detokenize & two minus signs   & \detokenize{--}  \\
Detokenize & one minus sing    & \detokenize{-}   \\
Detokenize & three minus signs & \detokenize{---} \\
\end{tabular}



\begin{tabular}{lcl}
Command    & applied to        & result                    \\\hline
Verb       & two minus signs   & \verb=--=                 \\
Detokenize & two minus signs   & \ttfamily{--}  \\
Detokenize & one minus sing    & \ttfamily{-}   \\
Detokenize & three minus signs & \ttfamily{---} \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{lcl}
Command    & applied to        & result                    \\\hline
Verb       & two minus signs   & \verb=--=                 \\
Detokenize & two minus signs   & {--}  \\
Detokenize & one minus sing    & {-}   \\
Detokenize & three minus signs & {---} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But then what's going on with `\verb` here?  I thought `\verb` just did catcode manipulations.

Comment: @A.Ellett Not quite: see the magic of `\@noligs`!

Comment: @A.Ellett verb (in classic tex and here) makes `-` _active_ and defined to insert a kern to prevent ligatures